# Trying to set up sublime text 2 to open files in unix terminal but getting an error

Tags: unix, terminal, cygwin

I'm trying to set up sublime text 2 to open a file in my cygwin terminal by using the command 'subl [file]'. I run the below command in my terminal as instructed in a number of sites

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

However, I get this error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/bin/subl': File exists
```

How do I work around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using 'alias', instead?

Add a line to your .bashrc file similar to:

alias subl='/cygdrive/c/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'

Then do a 'source .bashrc' command to load the new alias.

Comment: I still get a: No such file or directory error when I try to run the subl command after running the alias command above

Comment: try this
alias subl='/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe'

Answer (score 3):

Try this on a Mac:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/subl
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on Windows, right? That directory you're trying to point to is the directory for the Mac OS install of Sublime Text 2. You'll probably want something more like this, though adjust the path to sublime_text.exe to match where yours is:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is some directory in your PATH (`echo $PATH` to find out) so that your subl command will work from anywhere. Then you will be able to do `subl .` from any project directory to open that project in Sublime.